# How to search using the twitter API by country?

Tags: geolocation, twitter

Ideally I would like to be able to search tweets by country however `search/tweets` endpoint only supports geocode in the format of `"latitude,longitude,radius"` unlike the streaming endpoint which you can set a bounding box.

**How do you best search by country?**

As a simple solution I have thought about calculating the centre of the bounding box along with the smallest radius to remain in the bounding box.